# Doubt in Gallian Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have a doubt in Gallian *Algebra,* Example 10, Chapter 17: Factorization of Polynomials.

In the example, it was required to construct a field of $8$ elements, they got the required field as
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]}{x^{3}+x+1}.
$$
In that example, they further stated,
$x^3+x+1 + \langle x^3+x+1 \rangle = 0 + \langle x^{3}+x+1 \rangle$ implies
$x^3 + \langle x^3+x+1 \rangle = x+1 + \langle x^3+x+1 \rangle$.
This I am not getting. How this implies
$x^3 + \langle x^3+x+1 \rangle = x+1 + \langle x^3+x+1 \rangle$?
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

$x^3 - (x + 1) = x^3 + x + 1$ (since $-1 = 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$) and $x^3 - (x + 1) \in I$ is exactly the condition that $x^3 + I = (x + 1) + I$.

Also, once you have proved various facts about quotient rings, it is often easier to write these relations as $x^3 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod I \iff x^3 \equiv - (x + 1) \pmod I$.